# How to execute 100+ APIs using C# efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I am using C# with ASP NET Web Api solution (.net7.0)
The idea is that I can take over 100 POST requests, potentially going as high 1000s of requests, execute an API, each request which will open a database connection - however the database is set up with unlimited connections allowed. So I don't think that's a problem

These are the trials I have gone with so far:

None seem to work correctly.

```
var syntaxCommands = GetCommands();

//Test One
//ERROR - Timeout error
var tasks = new List<Task<object>>();
foreach (var cmd in syntaxCommands)
{
    tasks.Add(_syntaxExecutor.Execute(cmd));
}
var testResult = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

//Test Two
//Takes way too long
foreach (var command in syntaxCommands)
{
    await Task.Run(() => _syntaxExecutor.Execute(command));
}

//Test Three
Parallel.ForEach(syntaxCommands, async e =>
{
    await Task.Run(() => _syntaxExecutor.Execute(e));
});
```

The code to execute the API:

```
    public async Task<object> Execute(SyntaxCommand command)
    {
        var json = GetJson(command);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            try
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44346/SyntaxExecutor", content);
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseBody;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"D:\API-LOAD-Tests\logs-api.txt", ex.Message);
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    private string GetJson(SyntaxCommand command)
    {
        var updatedSyntax = command.Syntax.Replace(@"""", @"\""");
        var json = @$"""syntax"": ""{updatedSyntax}"", ""replacementVariableId"": {command.VariableId}, ""hierarchyId"": {command.HierarchyId}";
        json = json.Insert(0, "{");
        json = json.Insert(json.Length, "}");
        return json;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`Parallel.ForEach` is not `Task`-aware so it will just use parallelization to start tasks, but they all will run in parallel and usually you don't want to hit database with unconstrained number of simultaneous requests. You can use [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-7.0) - something along these lines:

```cs
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(syntaxCommands, async (cmd, ct) => await _syntaxExecutor.Execute(cmd));
```

And then play with it's settings to enable empirically find the optimal parallelization settings to pass (which will depend on your setup - the database and actual queries):

```cs
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    syntaxCommands, 
    new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 // here
    },
    async (cmd, ct) => ...);
```

Comment: I am testing these out now, so far seems good.. although from what I know is I am meant to be using all threads available so I didnt set any limits on this. 
Thank you!

Comment: @user98 by default `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is equal to the CPU count as far as I remember. "all threads" is very vague definition, process can create A LOT of them, but it does not make sense in quite a lot of situations.

Comment: yeah all available threads as in what the CPU thread count is - and on the machine i am using its 14! the idea is this eventually will go onto a dedicated machine where only this application will be running, so all threads that can be used are wanted.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances are not supported. Path: $.MoveNextAction.

i did just get this error messsage also after running

Comment: @user98 without full repro it is hard to tell but it seems that you are trying to serialize something which should not be serialized. But it is another question.